# React-native not rendering string

Tags: react-native

So,I'm fetching html from my server and I render it with library:react-native-render-html

Some parts of the string are rendering fine but some of them are like this :

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 <Text style={styles.description}>
          {/* <Text>Testing...</Text> */}
          {currentPostDetails === null || currentPostDetails === undefined ? (
            'Loading...'
          ) : (
            <HTML
              html={currentPostDetails.text.replaceAll(
                'font-family:',
                '&quot;";',
              )}
            />
          )}
        </Text>
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: it seems like a library issue. Did you. try creating an issue on this library's github page ?

Comment: @BoraSumer not yet,I'm not sure yet, maybe the problem is in me

Comment: @user14587589 i’ve just noticed that you’ve used the `html` prop instead of the `source` one which was listed on the docs. Any reason for this?

Comment: I changed that too but still did not work

Comment: <HTML
                baseFontStyle={{fontFamily: 'normal'}}
                source={{
                  html: currentPostDetails.text.replaceAll(
                    'font-family:',
                    '&quot;";',
                  ),
                }}
              />

Comment: hmmm. possible to share this `styles.description`? will like to try it out on my end and see if it is rendering in the same manner as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `<Text>` component you used to wrap the child components is at fault. `<Text>` works best when it is rendering plain text instead of complex component like `<HTML>`.

Try wrapping the child components with the `<View>` component instead, like this:

```
<View style={styles.description}>
  {/* <Text>Testing...</Text> */}
  {currentPostDetails === null || currentPostDetails === undefined ? (
    <Text>Loading...</Text>
  ) : (
    <HTML
      html={currentPostDetails.text.replaceAll(
        'font-family:',
        '&quot;";',
      )}
    />
  )}
</View>
```